# how to check value with JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="pageName" name="pageName">
<option value="">Select one....</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="value1">value1</option>
<option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
```

I selected All and the output

`$("select#pageName").val()=='All'`     -- true

But, I selected 'Select one....' and the output is below **WHY?**  please

`$("select#pageName").val()=="Select one...."`    -- false

How can i get below also 'true' please.....

Comment: use text()...............

Comment: `<option value="">` The value is not `"Select one...."`

Comment: If you set attribute value, val() method returns this attribute value. Removing attribute value will fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/T6PtL/

Comment: `.val()` sets/gets the `value` attribute for the given field. Your value for `"Select one..."` is `""` which is why your condition fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.val()`, jQuery return the current value of the selected element. It will return the attribute `value` of the selected element.

That beign said, the value of `select one...` is `''` (empty string) and the value of `All` is `'All'`. So you could do :

```
$("select#pageName").val()=="" //value of Select one...
```

or (note that this is not a good practice)

```
$("select#pageName :selected").text() == 'Select one...'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$("select#pageName").val()==""
```

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) get the current value of your `select` element based on the `value` attribute of your `option`.

In your case, the first option has empty value so you need to compare it with empty string.

If you want to keep your selector, you can either add value to your first option as `Select one....` or you can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("select#pageName").text()=="Select one...."
```

Comment: or remove attribute value for this option as val() will returns the property of the SELECT DOM node

Answer (score 2):

In order to work that you need to use, because `val` attribute is empty in this case

```
$("select#pageName").text()=="Select one...."
```

or

```
$("select#pageName").val()==""
```

these two will return `true`

Or you can set value attribute then it will return true

```
<option value="Select one....">Select one....</option>
```

```
$("select#pageName").val()=="Select one...."
```

Answer (score 2):

The `val()` method returns the value of the `value` attribute. In your case, you'd probably want

```
<option value="Select one...">Select one...</option>
```

or

```
$("select#pageName").val()==""
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of the control, you need to use:

```
$("select#pageName").val('All');
```

or (another example)

```
$("select#pageName").val('value1');
```

To read the value of the control, use:

```
var somevarname = $("select#pageName").val();
```

Note that the above reads the contents of the `value` attribute. Therefore, on the `Select One` entry, the value attribute is blank, so you will read a defined variable with no content.

If you wish to read the value of the text between the option tags (for the selected item), use:

```
$("select#pageName :selected").text()
```

---

Here is an example for you:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3XYt/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<select id="pageName" name="pageName">
    <option value="">Select one....</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
<div id="sumpin">
    <input id="myButt" type="button" value="Set Select Value" />
    <input id="urButt" type="button" value="Read Select Value" />
</div>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$("select#pageName").change(function(){
    var pn = $("select#pageName").val(); //shortcut: use $(this).val();
    alert( pn );
});
$('#myButt').click(function() {
    var toset = prompt("Type: All or value1 or value2");
    $("select#pageName").val(toset);
});
$('#urButt').click(function() {
    alert( $("select#pageName").val() );
});
```